# Operant conditioning algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, artificial-life

What's the best way to implement real time operant conditioning (supervised reward/punishment-based learning) for an agent? Should I use a neural network (and what type)? Or something else?

I want the agent to be able to be trained to follow commands like a dog. The commands would be in the form of gestures on a touchscreen. I want the agent to be able to be trained to follow a path (in continuous 2D space), make behavioral changes on command (modeled by FSM state transitions), and perform sequences of actions.

The agent would be in a simulated physical environment.

Comment: `What's the best way..` in the field of AI is seldom a good question. There are a LOT into it, and usually what fits perfectly for one problem is bad for a different one. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is the agent exactly? What algorithm does it use? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reinforcement Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning) is a good machine learning algorithm for your problem.

The basic reinforcement learning model consists of:

- a set of environment states `S` (you have a 2d space discretized in some way, which is the dog's current position, if you want to do continuous 2d-space, you might need a neural network to serve as the value function mapper.)
- a set of actions `A` ( you mentioned the dog performs sequences of actions, e.g., move, rotate)
- rules of transitioning between states ( your dog's position transition can be modeled by FSM)
- rules that determine the scalar immediate reward `r` of a transition (When reaching the target position, you might want to give the dog a big reward, while small rewards are also welcomed at intermediate milestones)
- rules that describe what the agent observes. (the dog might have a limited view, for example, only the 4 or 8 neighboring cells are viewable, below figure is an example showing the dog's current position `P` and the 4 neighboring cells that are viewable to the dog.)

[image]

To find the optimal policy, you can start with the model-free technique - [q-learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning).

Comment: -1 RF is not an algorithm. It's a very general problem definition. Thus it cannot be the answer to this question.

Comment: Yes, you can say RL is not an algorithm. It's a model, or problem definition. What I am trying to point out is that the OP can use the value-function approach to derive an **online algorithm** in order to train the agent to learn what are the best actions under various states. This is the core idea of RL, right?

Comment: Okay, in that case I should probably use an LSTM neural network. I did a little reading and came across temporal difference learning (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_difference), which is a type of reinforcement learning that seems to be what I'm looking for. Thanks!